# Seaborn light_palette including white in cmap

Tags: python, seaborn, pandas-styles

Normally when using 1-color seaborn color palettes such as [light_palette](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.light_palette.html), the user doesn't care about the color white.  However, since I am using this to pass a cmap into a pandas df.style object I want the minimum value to include white.

Basically I want this

```
sns.palplot(sns.light_palette("green"))
```

to include a white portion

[image: n]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a [cubehelix palette](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.cubehelix_palette.html#seaborn.cubehelix_palette) using `start=2` for green, `rot=0` to only have greens, `dark=0.4` to have the darkest color not too dark and `light=1` to have white as the lightest color:

```py
import seaborn as sns
sns.palplot(sns.cubehelix_palette(start=2, rot=0, dark=0.4, light=1))
```

[image: resulting palette]

Comment: Wow super useful, didn't know about the `choose_cubehelix_palette` function